# Bash Script to move files based on their Prefix

Tags: bash, mkdir

I take pictures for my job on three different cameras. I am looking to automate the process of organising these to folders based on the first 3 letters and then the filetype.

Unfortunately my bash script syntax knowledge is non existent and so I can't figure out more than creating the directories..

An eg of the incoming files:

```
HAM1234.JPG
HAM1234.RAW
HDR1234.JPG
HDR1234.RAW
STL1234.JPG
STL1234.RAW
```

These would go into 3 folders

```
HAM - REF/{RAW,JPG}
HDR - HDRI/{RAW,JPG}
STL - STILLS/{RAW,JPG}
```

With the filetypes being aligned.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Jason

Comment: You simply need globbing with `nullglob` disabled to populate the files. Use for loop to iterate on each result, then to get the first three letters, use `${filename:0:3}`; extension use `${filename%%*.}`. Use `case` or `[[ ]]` to do comparisons. `mkdir`'s `-p` option can be helpful too. Read Bash's manual. Post your work for suggestions.

Comment: Are there 3 or 6 folders? Do the directories already exist?

Comment: @Cyrus there are 9 folders in all, RAW and JPG for each camera (REF, HDRI, STILLS) plus the camera folders themselves. None of them exist. Ideally I want to be able to copy all of the images to one folder and run the script on the folder to sort it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown examples:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p {HAM\ -\ REF,HDR\ -\ HDRI,STL\ -\ STILLS}/{RAW,JPG}

shopt -s failglob

mv HAM*.JPG "HAM - REF/JPG"
mv HAM*.RAW "HAM - REF/RAW"

mv HDR*.JPG "HDR - HDRI/JPG"
mv HDR*.RAW "HDR - HDRI/RAW"

mv STL*.JPG "STL - STILLS/JPG"
mv STL*.RAW "STL - STILLS/RAW"
```

From `man bash`:

> `failglob`: If  set,  patterns which fail to match filenames during pathname expansion result in an expansion error.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer a very basic bash script based on your requirements and information you provided:

```
#!/bin/bash

for files in *
do
    if [ -f "$files" ]; then
        fileprefix=${files%%[0-9]*.*}
        case $fileprefix in
            HAM)
                if [ ! -d REF ]; then
                    mkdir REF;
                fi
                mv "$fileprefix"*.* REF
            ;;
        
            HDR)
                if [ ! -d HDRI ]; then
                    mkdir HDRI;
                fi
                mv "$fileprefix"*.* HDRI
            ;;
        
            STL)
                if [ ! -d STILLS ]; then
                    mkdir STILLS;
                fi
                mv "$fileprefix"*.* STILLS
            ;;
        esac
    fi
done
```

The first logic `for files in *` assumes the script itself and all the image files resides in the same directory i.e. PWD.

`if [ -f "$files" ]; then`
Only run the logic if the matching item in the iteration is a file

`fileprefix=${files%%[0-9]*.*}`
Extract the letters (first 3) and store it in variable `fileprefix`

After that a simple `switch-case` follows.

You can modify the script as per your needs.

Hope this answers your question.